# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am meeting up a window and hide it with `withdraw()` in it's original class. And then I opened a new window, I want to redisplay the first one when I close the second one.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Frame
import time
import tkinter as tk


class Return_Value_In_Entry:

    def __init__(self, Master):
        self.question_num = 0
        self.answer_list = []
        self.survey_num = 1
        self.survey_dict = dict()
        self.question_list = ["START", "FODO_easy", "CIBAN_hard", "AUBLM_easy", "GROLY_hard", "EMONV", "MAHES", "AORDI",
                          "LENUC", "RYORS", "BMHUT"]
        self.Master = Master
        self.Master.title("Welcome")
        self.Frame = tk.Frame(self.Master)
        self.Master.lbl = Label(self.Frame, text=self.question_list[self.question_num], font=("Courier", 44), width=30,
                            height=10)
        self.Master.lbl.pack()
        self.Entry = Entry(self.Frame)
        self.Entry.pack()
        self.Button = Button(self.Frame, text="Submit", command=self.Return, height=2)
        self.Button.pack()
        self.clock = Label(self.Frame, height=5)
        self.clock.pack()
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.Button_2 = Button(self.Frame, text="Exit", command=self.Exit, height=2)
        self.Button_2.pack()
        self.Frame.pack()

        def tick():
            time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            self.clock.config(text=time2)
            self.clock.after(200, tick)

        tick()

    def Return(self):
        print("time used = ", time.time() - self.start_time)
        self.question_num += 1
        self.TempVar = self.Entry.get()
        print(self.TempVar)
        self.answer_list.append(self.TempVar)

        if (self.question_num - 1) % 2 == 0 and (self.question_num - 1) != 0 and (self.question_num - 1) % 4 != 0:
            self.newWindow_1 = tk.Toplevel(self.Master)
            self.app_1 = survey_hard(self.newWindow_1)
    #Trying to hide the first window with withdraw() at here:

        self.Master.withdraw()

    if (self.question_num - 1) % 4 == 0 and (self.question_num - 1) != 0:
        self.newWindow_2 = tk.Toplevel(self.Master)
        self.app_2 = survey_set(self.newWindow_2)

    self.start_time = time.time()
    self.Master.lbl.configure(text=self.question_list[self.question_num])
    self.Entry.delete(0, 'end')

    def Exit(self):
        print(self.answer_list)
        self.Master.destroy()


class survey_hard:
    def __init__(self, Master):
        self.survey_num = 1
        self.survey_dict = dict()
        self.Master = Master
        self.Frame = tk.Frame(self.Master)
        self.Master.title("survey_hard")
        self.hard_label_1 = Label(self.Frame, text="Question_1")
        self.hard_entry_1 = Entry(self.Frame)
        self.hard_label_2 = Label(self.Frame, text="Question_2")
        self.hard_entry_2 = Entry(self.Frame)
        self.hard_button = Button(self.Frame, text="Submit", command=self.Next, height=2)
        self.hard_label_1.pack()
        self.hard_entry_1.pack()
        self.hard_label_2.pack()
        self.hard_entry_2.pack()
        self.hard_button.pack()
        self.Frame.pack()

    def Next(self):
        self.survey_dict[self.survey_num] = [self.hard_entry_1.get(), self.hard_entry_2.get()]
        self.survey_num += 1
        print(self.survey_dict)
        self.Master.destroy()
    #Want to show up the first window again here:
        the_main = Return_Value_In_Entry()
        the_main.Pop()


    class survey_set:
    ...... ......


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Return_Value_In_Entry(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It always gives me an error and warning message like this:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__return 
>   self.func(*args)
> File "/Users/HarryWuuu/PycharmProjects/untitled17/venv/111.py", line 89, in Next 
>   the_main = Return_Value_In_Entry()
> TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Master'
> ```

Comment: Your error is this line `the_main = Return_Value_In_Entry()`, needs to be `the_main = Return_Value_In_Entry(root)`. But: *" want to redisplay the first one"*, to do this, use `.tkraise()` using the reference from `class Return_Value_In_Entry`. Read [Raising TK Frames containing widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50953376/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Read this comment: [TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471835/typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument#comment95761531_54471835)

---

While calling `the_main = Return_Value_In_Entry()`, means you want to create an instance of `Return_Value_In_Entry` and assign this newly created instance to `the_main`.

Creating an instance of a class will call its `__init__` method.

In your case, `Return_Value_In_Entry.__init__` take two positional arguments. The first is `self`, which is omitted by Python, and the second is `Master`, which you forgot to set.